# UIWebView - Hide address bar when scrolling

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios4

I want to hide the address bar when I scroll in a `UIWebView` like in Safari so when the user scrolls down on the webpage, the menu bar gets pushed up so that the user can see the whole page like in Safari.

Anyone suggestions and/or tutorials?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's a framework called `WebKit` and a class called `UIWebView`, but as far as I know, nothing called `UIWebKit`. I've edited the title, but if I was mistaken, my apologies.

Answer (score 2):

Late answare, but if somebody needs this.

You can detect the scroll very easy. UIWebView conforms with UIScrollViewDelegate.

```
[webView.scrollView setDelegate:self];
```

and add method:

```
- (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
      if(scrollView.contentOffset.y == 0) {
          //show
      } else {
          //hide
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing stops you putting a `UINavigationBar` inside a `UIScrollView` with the `UIWebView`. Maybe that's over complicating it - but it will give the effect you are looking for.

Comment: However, this seems to cause the browser bar to overlap in iOS 4.3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this tutorial](http://mithin.wordpress.com/2009/08/26/detecting-taps-and-events-on-uiwebview-the-right-way/) to detect scrolling.  Then you can hide your address bar (I don't believe UIWebView includes one) when you detect the user scrolling.